Rotation of image not following my finger gesture the third time I put my finger to continue the rotation on my in a react native cli mobile app
I have spent over 3 weeks trying everything to figure this out. My goal is to allow rotation of this image by dragging the finger in the corner of the photo on the canvas I have the component on. Ideally, the user can put their finger on the rotation icon and rotate the image following the gesture direction. It works (kinda) - so it seems to do it the first 2 times (not perfectly) when I put my finger on it, follows how I am gesturing the move (so if I am trying to rotate right, it rotates). But without failing, the third time (or something the second time), it literally starts going in the reverse direction of what I am gesturing for it to rotate.
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, PanResponder, Animated, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

const Rotate = ({
  uri, initialRotation, onRotate
}) => {
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState(uri);
  const [rotation, setRotation] = useState(initialRotation || 0);
  const rotationIconRef = useRef(null);
  const initialAngleRef = useRef(0);


  
  const handleRotate = (dx, dy) => {
    const rotationSensitivity = 0.05; // Adjust this value for sensitivity
    let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * (180 / Math.PI) - initialAngleRef.current;

    console.log("Gesture dx:", dx, "Gesture dy:", dy);
    console.log("Calculated angle (before adjustment):", angle);

    // Apply a damping factor to reduce sensitivity
    const adjustedAngle = angle * rotationSensitivity;

    // Calculate the new rotation
    const newRotation = (rotation + adjustedAngle) % 360;

    // Normalize the new rotation to be within 0-360 degrees
    const normalizedRotation = newRotation < 0 ? newRotation + 360 : newRotation;

    setRotation(normalizedRotation);
    console.log("newRotation being set", normalizedRotation);
    console.log("Final angle (after adjustment):", adjustedAngle);
    onRotate(normalizedRotation);
  };


  const createRotatePanResponder = () => PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
      // Reset the initial angle reference when the gesture starts
      initialAngleRef.current = Math.atan2(gestureState.dy, gestureState.dx) * (180 / Math.PI);
    },
    onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => handleRotate(gestureState.dx, gestureState.dy), // Pass both dx and dy
    onPanResponderRelease: () => onRotate(rotation),
  }).panHandlers;

  

  return (
      </Animated.View>
          <View
            ref={rotationIconRef}
            style={[styles.rotateIconWrapper, styles.rotateSliderWrapper, { bottom: -15, left: -15 }]}
            {...createRotatePanResponder()}           >
            <Feather name="rotate-ccw" size={20} color="black" />
          </View>
    </Animated.View>
  );
  
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   rotateIconWrapper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 15,
    zIndex: 2,
  },
  rotateSliderWrapper: {
    left: -15,
    bottom: -15,
  },
});

export default Rotate;

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Just trying to figure out if I am missing some fundamental concept inadvertently causing this weird behavior.
